# Cascading delete for EF sqlite database tables

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, cascading-deletes

Could someone help me with writing the proper code for DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade please.
I have the two classes `Account` and `Schedule` defined as follow (`Account` can have many `Schedule` objects):

```
 public class Account : IdentityUser
        { 
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
    
            public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
        }
        public class Schedule
        {
                public string AccountAccountId { get; set; }
                public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
                public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }

... and the context

     public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<Account>
        {
            public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
            public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            {
                // connect to sqlite database
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"));
            }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                //modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasMany(e => e.RefreshTokens).WithOne(e => e.Account).IsRequired();
    
                modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
                .HasOne(b => b.Account)
                .HasMany(a => a.Schedules) <--- Error
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade); <--- Error
            }
        }
```

I am following this article [link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method) but I am getting errors in my `DataContext` when trying to do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
        .HasOne(b => b.Account)<--- error
        .HasMany(a => a.Schedules) 
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  And -- are you getting the error/errors on starting your application or when trying to delete an Account?  ... first thing that occurs to me is that you don't actually have an `Account` or `AccountId` defined in your `Schedule` object, so your model classes don't match your ``modelBuilder.Entity` setup.

Comment: Its a compilation error(`Schedule' does not contain definition for an `Account[). But in the example that I follow they also don't have AuthorId  in the Book class.

Comment: I believe that you may not be defining a known/acceptable key/index (probably Primary Key) for the Account (column Id or Account Id). See https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions

Comment: I just don't know what to add to my class definition for the code `            modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
        .HasOne(b => b.Account)<--- error
        .HasMany(a => a.Schedules) 
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade); ` to compile

Comment: I have added to Schedule the `AccountAccountId ` and now how do i fix the expression in my `DataContext`

Answer (score 0):

This doc is incomplete. Maybe you should try this https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration first.
To define a one-to-many relationship.You will need to make the Schedule class like below

```
    public class Schedule
    {
        public string AccountAccountId { get; set; }
        public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Account? Account { get;set; }
    }
```

Use `Account?` here to make foreignkey AccounId nullable.
Generally use "s" stands for "schedule" and your schedule class now has a "Account" field now.
Then you could define the one-to many relationship use

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Account)
                .WithMany(a => a.Schedules);
```

or

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account()
                .HasMany(a => a.Schedules)
                .WithOne(s => s.Account);
```

They have the same result. Must use `Has..` as first behind the entity then use `With`. Your code actually use 2 `Has...` method.

The `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);` could turn to be error if you hadn't add `?` to `Account?` to make it nullable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without modifying `Schedule` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasMany<Schedule>(a => a.Schedules)
                .WithOne()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```